# Representing hierarchical data using a DataGrid/GridView control

Tags: c#, asp.net, controls

I do not have access to third party components on this project. I think I only have access to the built-in DataGrid and GridView controls.

Is there a good example for representing hierarchical data (inside a grid - Master /Details) in a built-in ASP.NET server control?

I am looking for an expand/collapse tree structure kind of implementation.

Comment: System.Windows.Forms.TreeView is not a third party component, why don't you have access to that ?

Comment: @SS'Kain' - thanks for your input I am talking about ASP.NET.

Answer (score 1):

You're after the [TreeView Server Control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/e8z5184w%28v=VS.100%29.aspx).

This is built into ASP.NET (System.Web.UI.WebControls).

**Code sample from the Microsoft Reference (for static content):**

```
<asp:TreeView ID="MyTreeView" Runat="server">
  <Nodes>
    <asp:TreeNode Value="Child1" Expanded="True" Text="1">
      <asp:TreeNode Value="Grandchild1" Text="A" />
      <asp:TreeNode Value="Grandchild2" Text="B" />
    </asp:TreeNode>
    <asp:TreeNode Value="Child2" Text="2" />
    <asp:TreeNode Value="Child3" Expanded="True" Text="3">
      <asp:TreeNode Value="Grandchild1" Text="A" />
    </asp:TreeNode>
  </Nodes>
</asp:TreeView>
```

You can also build a Treeview Dynamically.

There are good samples [at MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/e8z5184w%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) for this.

Comment: Sorry if my question wasn't clear. I have added more details. I wanted the hierachial data representation in a grid. You have one row displaying all the data say application ID and when you click on the ID it shows details for that ID. Once again Thank you. I appreciate your support.

Comment: For that, I typically use a Datalist inside of a Gridview, or a Gridview inside of a gridview. Hopefully I get some time to type up a tutorial here.

Answer (score 0):

Please go through [this](http://nilthakkar.blogspot.in/2009/05/nested-gridview-in-aspnet-20.html), though it is not having sample code, it helps you to get started.

Code is for Asp.net 2.0 and at that time Jquery was not that much popular so code uses JavaScript so you might want to  change few things while implementing it. Adapt it as per your  need.